# trying to build a MODBUS packet with scapy

Tags: python-2.7, scapy, modbus-tcp

i'm trying to build a MODBUS packet with scapy,
**but  Wireshark can't recognize it. i mean, the MODBUS interpreted as the TCP data.**

here is the python code of Scapy:

```
from scapy.all import *


class Modbus(Packet):
    name = "Modbus/tcp"
    fields_desc = [ ShortField("Transaction Identifier", 1),
                    ShortField("Protocol Identifier", 0),
                    ShortField("Length", 5),
                    XByteField("Unit Identifier",0),
                    ]

def make_test():
    pkt = TCP(sport=502, dport=502)
    return Ether()/IP(src="5.5.5.101",dst="5.5.5.100")/pkt/Modbus()


while True:
    send(make_test())
```

someone has an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Please specify the python version and the output (error) of your code.

Comment: Hey, i am using Python 2.7.12, but i don't get an error while the code is running. instead, Wireshark does not recognise the packet as MODBUS...

Comment: Use the tags to specify the python version.

Comment: FYI Scapy already has a modbus module: https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/contrib/modbus.py you just need to import it for it to be loaded

Answer (score 1):

I ran the same code with 2 changes and Wireshark recognized it as Modbus:

First, as you are sending empty packets (n=0), the default value of the length field has to be 2, not 5 (n+2 according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus#Modbus_TCP_frame_format_(primarily_used_on_Ethernet_networks)).

Second, you're missing the field Function Code.

So, in the end my fields_desc looks like this:

```
fields_desc = [ ShortField("Transaction Identifier", 1),
                    ShortField("Protocol Identifier", 0),
                    ShortField("Length", 2),
                    XByteField("Unit Identifier",0),
                    ByteField("Function Code", 0)
                    ]
```

Wireshark complains because 0 is not actually a valid function code, but it correctly interprets it as modbus.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 3-way TCP handshake in your code, which means no communication channel has been established between the hosts. To solve the problem socket needs to be created.

Here is my code, might be helpful for others.

```
from scapy.all import *
import time

# Modbus ADU
class ModbusTCP(Packet):
    name = "Modbus/TCP"
    fields_desc = [ ShortField("Transaction Identifier", 1),
                    ShortField("Protocol Identifier", 0),
                    ShortField("Length", 6),
                    XByteField("Unit Identifier", 247),
                    ]

# Modbus PDU
class Modbus(Packet):
    name = "Modbus"
    fields_desc = [ XByteField("Function Code", 4),
                    ShortField("Reference Number", 1),
                    ShortField("Word Count", 2),
                    ]

# Create a socket and connect
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("192.168.95.10", 502))   # IP and port
ss = StreamSocket(s, Raw)

while True:
    try:
        # Encapsulate modbus inside the raw data, then send and receive
        # Anything can be done with response
        ss.sr1(Raw(ModbusTCP()/Modbus()))
        time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

References:

- [Using the kernel’s TCP stack](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layers/tcp.html)
- [Sending & recieving packets](https://0xbharath.github.io/art-of-packet-crafting-with-scapy/scapy/sending_recieving/index.html)